# Slow performance on MariaDB 10.7.6 using a query with many subselects

Tags: sql, mariadb, common-table-expression, database-performance

Running on a M1 Max macOS 12.6 with MariaDB 10.7 installed via homebrew.

I'm having trouble isolating the reason this is slower than I expected. I expected 2 to 10 minutes, but I'm seeing more than an hour. There are 57 million records, it seems to be scanning 55 million. At the bottom, I have listed the queries and the counts of each. I suspect the **Using temporary; Using filesort**. I have added an index on most referenced columns.

I am looking for more ideas to try to resolve this performance. If this is the best I can do, that is also a valid outcome. I am also looking at migrating to full text searching, but I am not ready for that yet.

ANALYZE results in table format:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | r_rows | filtered | r_filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | RPost | index_merge | rpost_idx_6, rpost_idx_7, rpost_idx_8 | rpost_idx_6, rpost_idx_7, rpost_idx_8 | 6,6,6 | NULL | 6176002 | 55104309.00 | 100.00 | 0.02 | Using intersect( rpost_idx_6, rpost_idx_7, rpost_idx_8); Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 11 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | RPost | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | test.RPost.Id | 1 | 1.00 | 100.00 | 100.00 |  |
| 10 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | RPost | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | test.RPost.Id | 1 | 1.00 | 100.00 | 100.00 |  |
| 9 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | RPost | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | test.RPost.Id | 1 | 1.00 | 100.00 | 100.00 |  |
| 8 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | History | ref | posthistory_idx_1, history_idx_2, history_idx_4 | history_idx_1 | 4 | test.RPost.Id | 1 | 2.61 | 2.98 | 0.78 | Using where |
| 7 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | History | ref | posthistory_idx_1 ,history_idx_2, history_idx_4 | history_idx_1 | 4 | test.RPost.Id | 1 | 2.61 | 50 | 96.34 | Using where |
| 6 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY |  | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2 | 2.00 | 100.00 | 0.59 | Using where |
| 12 | DERIVED | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | No tables used |
| 13 | UNION | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | No tables used |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union12,13> | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2.00 | NULL | NULL |  |
| 5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY |  | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2 | 2.00 | 100.00 | 0.12 | Using where |
| 2 | DERIVED | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | No tables used |
| 3 | UNION | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | No tables used |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union2,3> | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2.00 | NULL | NULL |  |

The query:

```
WITH Common as (
  SELECT '% strings %' AS Value
  UNION
  SELECT '% tofind %'
),
MyRPost (Id, STitle, SBody, Queued, Frozen)
AS
(
SELECT
  RPost.Id,
  (
    SELECT count(*) FROM Common
    WHERE RPost.Title Like Common.Value
  ) AS STitle,
  (
    SELECT count(*) FROM Common
    WHERE RPost.Body Like Common.Value
  ) AS SBody,
  (SELECT count(History.TypeId) FROM History
          WHERE History.PostId = RPost.Id
            AND History.TypeId BETWEEN 1 AND 9
  )%2 AS Queued,
  (SELECT count(History.TypeId) FROM History
          WHERE History.PostId = RPost.Id
            AND History.TypeId BETWEEN 10 AND 19
  )%2 AS Frozen
  FROM RPost
  WHERE RPost.CompletedDate IS NULL
    AND RPost.CancelDate is NULL
    AND RPost.PausedDate IS NULL
)
SELECT STitle, SBody, Id, Queued, Frozen,
  (SELECT RPost.ParentId FROM RPost WHERE MyRPost.Id=RPost.Id) as OriginId,
  (SELECT RPost.PostTypeId FROM RPost WHERE MyRPost.Id=RPost.Id) as Type,
  (SELECT RPost.Title FROM RPost WHERE MyRPost.Id=RPost.Id) as Title
FROM MyRPost
WHERE (Queued+Frozen) = 0
  AND (STitle+SBody) > 1
ORDER BY (STitle+SBody), Id
```

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE History (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    TypeId SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PostId INT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE RPost (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Title varchar(256),
    Body text NULL,
    PostTypeId TINYINT NOT NULL ,
    ParentId INT,
    CompletedDate DATETIME,
    CancelDate DATETIME,
    PausedDate DATETIME
);
```

Counts:

| Query | Count |
| --- | --- |
| select * from rpost | 56 million |
| remove non-NULL CompletedDate / CancelDate / PausedDate | 55 million |
| now remove (Queued+Frozen) = 0 | 15 million |
| finally process likes | 8505 |

Answer (score 1):

Consider refactoring the query for conditional aggregation without the nested sub-selects:

```sql
WITH Common AS (
  SELECT '% strings %' AS Value
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '% tofind %'
),
MyRPost (Id, STitle, SBody, Queued, Frozen) AS (
  SELECT
     r.Id,
     COUNT(ct.Value) AS STitle,
     COUNT(cb.Value) AS SBody,
     SUM(h.TypeId BETWEEN 1 AND 9) % 2 AS Queued,
     SUM(h.TypeId BETWEEN 10 AND 19) % 2 AS Frozen
  FROM RPost r
  LEFT JOIN Common ct ON r.Title LIKE ct.Value
  LEFT JOIN Common cb ON r.Body LIKE cb.Value
  LEFT JOIN History h ON h.PostId = r.Id
  WHERE r.CompletedDate IS NULL
    AND r.CancelDate is NULL
    AND r.PausedDate IS NULL
  GROUP BY r.Id
  HAVING (Queued + Frozen) = 0
     AND (STitle + SBody) > 1
)

SELECT 
   m.STitle, m.SBody, m.Id, m.Queued, m.Frozen,
   r.ParentId AS OriginId, r.PostTypeId AS Type, r.Title
FROM MyRPost m
LEFT JOIN RPost r ON m.Id = r.Id
ORDER BY (m.STitle + m.SBody), m.Id
```

Comment: My query returned 8505 records, this returned 177084. The join on History needs to be removed, but I'm not sure how to just get the highest Id value of the two (Queued/Frozen). I don't need the sum, just true false status. (1 or 3 queued = true, 2 or 4 = false for example).

Comment: I almost wanted to mention, the `LIKE` joins may return joined duplicates if Title and Body share the same string matches. I wonder if an OR condition helps: `LEFT JOIN Common c ON (r.Title LIKE c.Value OR r.Body LIKE c.Value)` without joining `Common` twice. But `LIKE` + `OR` performance may be challenging.